# Rows Holding the Group-wise mysql

Tags: mysql

i have simple table and need to group by duplicate items , also i need to get min with holding row i read this tutorial work , but not sum grouped item level
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

```
+------------+------+-------+----------+----+
| descendant | deep | level | ancestor | id |
+------------+------+-------+----------+----+
|          2 |    0 |     1 |        2 |  1 |
|          4 |    1 |     1 |        2 |  2 |
|          4 |    2 |     1 |       45 |  3 |
|          6 |    1 |     1 |     1368 |  4 |
|          6 |    2 |     1 |        6 |  5 |
|          6 |    3 |     1 |   123456 |  6 |
+------------+------+-------+----------+----+
```

i need  group  descendant and just show min deep row , bellow code work and not add level

```
SELECT  descendant,deep,ancestor, count(level)  FROM test as s1

         where deep = (SELECT min(s2.deep)
              FROM test s2
              WHERE s1.descendant = s2.descendant  )

 group by descendant
```

my Considered  result

```
descendant | deep | ancestor |count(level)

2          |  0   |    2     |   1
4          |  1   |    2     |   2
6          |  1   |    1368  |   3
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance...

All you need is a GROUP BY clause with the MAX aggregate function:

```
SELECT id, MAX(rev)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
```

but with inner join we can holding row wit max or sum value

```
SELECT a.id, a.rev, a.contents
FROM YourTable a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(rev) rev
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY id
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.rev = b.rev
```